# Why doesn't String.Substring(String.Length - 2, 1) work?

Tags: c#

So I got this user input of a product code, and I want to get the last digit as that is the check digit I need to validate the code with.

And instead of using a magic number, I wanted to use something more flexible which will always return the last digit no matter how long or short the input was.

But I keep getting yelled at for trying to implicitly convert 'string' to 'int' if I try to use the `.Length` property as a starting index.

```
int checkDigit = input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 1);
```

Doesn't String.Length return a number?
It works like a charm in `for` loops, why not here?

Comment: It's complaining about `int checkDigit = `. Substring returns a string, not an integer.

Comment: You need to convert it into int... `int checkDigit = (int)input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 1);` or `int checkDigit = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 1));`.

Comment: YES!

Got it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int checkDigit = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 1));
```

Or better, in case

```
int checkDigit = 0;

Int32.TryParse(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 1), out checkDigit);
```

You might also want to check if the input is long enough:

```
if (input.Length > 3)
```

Comment: I think, in the final check, `input.Length > 1` would be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit trigger happy!

Answer (score 0):

The [String.Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length, you cannot assign them to an integer variable as you are doing.

If you change the type of target of this assignment to string means your code will work, what I mean to say is :

```
string checkDigit = input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 1);
```